# This tag has [collapse]d

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

This seems to be a subset of [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) tags, since most of the questions also have [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) and most of them are about collapsing an element of a menu. It doesn't seem to be a very useful tag, in the same category as [div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/div). Apparently there's no need for cleanup, since all the questions already have their fitting tags.

Should we let [collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapse) join the current downfall of all the bad tags?

Comment: Is an 8 year gap normal between requesting burnination and actually going through with the burnination?

Comment: @M.Justin totally. There is a huge backlog of burnination requests that mods have finally got the manpower (well, more like a foxpower) to address. We should be glad the tags have started to burn brightly :)

Comment: @M.Justin This is one of the older requests being burninated now, but yeah, there's years of work in the backlog, and years being added regularly. I don't have a distribution chart or anything, but wouldn't surprise me if there are 10 year old burnination requests by now, and if there aren't, there certainly will be soon. 2-3 years of no burninations (the mod previously engaged in burninations stopped for reasons:tm: that are entirely their business) didn't help with the backlog either. But the more traction burninations get, the more burninations can be performed

Comment: Just came here to ask are we done with the puns? :-(

Comment: @BartoszKP Puns aren't allowed during the featured and burnination phases. They're still allowed before and after the burn (or a failed phase 2, if applicable)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Thanks for clarifying! Makes sense :)

Answer (score 53):

Obviously, the tag should be burninated.

Many things can be collapsed: values, columns, bars, HTML stuff (too many things in HTML can be collapsed), etc. making it too ambiguous. No one can be an expert in [collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapse) because of the things that can be collapsed and the language that the question is about. While collapsing is a common term in JavaScript and HTML, there are also R and Python questions.

Answer (score 13):

[collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapse) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Questions about the [collapsing action of a UI element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disclosure_widget) generally doesn't need a tag to represent the action. Make sure the question has relevant language and, if applicable, framework or library tags:

  - [android-collapsingtoolbarlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout)
  - [jquery-mobile-collapsible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile-collapsible)
  - [collapsiblepanelextender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapsiblepanelextender) (ASP.net AJAX control toolkit)
  - [expander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expander) (C# WPF, although the tag wiki doesn't mention it and 1/5 are mistagged)
  - [details-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/details-tag) (HTML5 `<details>`)
  - [react-native-collapsible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native-collapsible)
  - [react-navigation-collapsible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-navigation-collapsible)
  - [expandablelistview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expandablelistview) + [expandablelistadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expandablelistadapter) (android)
- Questions with the [collapsable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapsable), [expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expand) or [expandable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expandable) tags should also have those removed
- Questions about collapsing/expanding one of multiple panels in a row (an [accordion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(GUI))) should be retagged to [accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accordion)
- Questions about collapsing/expanding sections of code should be retagged to [code-folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-folding)
- Questions about collapsing/expanding nodes in a [tree view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_view) should be retagged to [treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/treeview)
- Questions about CSS border-collapsing should be retagged to [border-collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/border-collapse)
- Questions about CSS margin collapsing should be retagged to [margin-collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/margin-collapsing)
- Questions about collapsing data (multiple rows into one, by a column or other expression) should be retagged to [aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aggregate) and/or [group-by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/group-by) ([pandas-groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-groupby) on Pandas dataframes was made a synonym of the latter)

## Progress:

The [collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapse) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=collapse),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcollapse%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcollapse%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcollapse%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcollapse%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=254311)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapse) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapse) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapse) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: When retagging, I found two more interesting tags: [tag:hide] and [tag:show]. Both have wiki excerpt talking about visually hiding/showing elements, esp. in HTML. `hide` and `collapse` describe fairly similar behaviour: the former makes element completely disappear and the latter - greatly reduce in size and have most content hidden. What is proper relation between them (unrelated? synonyms? contextual synonyms which can be manually retagged? rarely related, so [hide] is not applicable to most of the posts? anything else?)? It's kinda obvious for me that [hide] should not be burninated, though

Comment: This tag is a real rabbit hole... Both those tags (plus the combination [show-hide]) [has a burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294340/hide-the-whole-show-hide-show). We can't start fully burning those tags without going through the full process separately, but I'll argue it's fine to remove them when observed on collapse questions (i.e. same treatment as [expand]). Doesn't  really matter though, the combined overlap between collapse and hide and show combined is 19 questions, so it isn't like not removing them causes a huge amount of work if consensus is to kill [hide]

Comment: Should the questions be retagged to anything, [[tag:accordion]] for example?

Comment: @Bergi Assuming the question is about an accordion, sure. Feel free to add it to the usage guidance - I struggled finding possible additional tags when I looked, so the guidance is a bit less comprehensive this time

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I found some and added them to the guidance

Comment: "*Questions about the collapsing action of a UI element generally doesn't need a tag to represent the action.*" - I kind of disagree with this. Maybe we don't need a tag for the action, but a tag for the kind of element is useful. And much more useful in combination with a tag for a specfic UI library, than creating individual tags for every component in that library. Btw this type of UI element is known as a [disclosure widget or expander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disclosure_widget), and we do have [tag:disclosure] and [tag:expander] tags for them.

Comment: @Bergi [HTML details element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52491581) was the first retag guidance item on my mind.