# ​[Hide] the whole [show-hide] [show]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

I recently came across across the [show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/show), [hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hide), and [show-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/show-hide) tags. According to their wikis, they typically refer to showing or hiding HTML elements, though it does add the caveat that it could be more extensive. On many questions including this one: [Post 30175162](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175162/hiding-next-and-previous-buttons-when-first-or-last-items-are-active), all three tags are included.

There are more than 1500 posts that use these tags.

My thoughts:

1. The tag adds nothing meaningful to the question. Whoever heard of a specialist in using jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()`.
2. The names are super ambiguous. [show-hide] is the least ambiguous but still not good.
3. It's on topic - people have issues with this (assuming we peg down a few of the more useful possible definitions)

If people think the tag is indeed useful, I suggest just combining them all together with [show-hide], otherwise they should just be deleted.

Comment: [show-hide] and [hide] the [show]

Comment: I vote for combining.  Showing and hiding UI elements is a common task with common problems.