# This tag has gone into [hiding]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

The tag [hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hiding) has 204 questions tagged right now, but no usage guidance or tag wiki. The questions are about hiding *something* from the users mostly.

The four criteria for burnination:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? **No**
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? **Not sure, it's broad**
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? **No**
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? **No**

Can we burninate it?

Comment: Kill it with fire.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +61/-3. A1 (Saying Yes) +21/-2.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +99/-4. A1 (Saying Yes) +61/-2. The community has voted in favor of burninating the tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hiding) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overriding) for questions related to hiding members using inheritence.
- Use [member-hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/member-hiding) for questions related to declaring a class member in a derived class with the same name as a method in a base class, without using the language's explicit "override" mechanism.  E.g.: the [`new` modified in c#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier).

## Progress:

The [hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hiding) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=hiding),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhiding%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhiding%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhiding%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhiding%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193107)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=354620)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hiding) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hiding) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hiding) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: OK, so there are some questions about the [new modifier in c#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier): *When used as a declaration modifier, the `new` keyword explicitly hides a member that is inherited from a base class.*  This isn't the same as overriding as the base class member is still present on the derived class, it's just less accessible and replaced with something else.  See [this answer by Erik Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1510702/3744182) for details.  What are we to do with these?

Comment: I'm not that sure of the exact tag there, @dbc, but if you feel that there needs to be a new tag created for that, please do feel free to create one, and update this answer asking users to use the tag. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well there's already [tag:member-hiding] and [tag:method-hiding] which would seem to apply.  In fact the original answer brings these two up along with "property-hiding" (which currently has no questions).  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/544702) gives "member" as the more general term **for c# at least**, so should we use that (and tag c# method-hiding questions)?  [tag:method-hiding] is more popular for c# though at 43 questions vs 8 questions.

Comment: Hmm, [tag:member-hiding] has guidance *Declaring a class member in a derived class with the same name as a method in a base class.* so let's go with that.

Comment: @dbc, ah, cool. Thanks. Would it make sense to merge the [method-hiding] and [member-hiding] tags, atleast in terms of C#?

Comment: Probably.  But there are [tag:java] and a few [tag:c++] questions there also and I frame no hypotheses about what to do with them.

Comment: That sounds fine to me, thanks. While we're on the same topic of tags, can I get a small help from you on the C# related portion in this other tag merge request? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381728/4099593. Thanks for your help. (top users in the tag helping out makes it really simple for me, so thanks a lot)

Comment: Re your request for https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381728/4099593, I retagged [Override And Call Base Property Set Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236874/override-and-call-base-property-set-method) but [C#: Generics, Polymorphism And Specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486933/c-generics-polymorphism-and-specialization) seems to be a request for how to implement c++ template specialization in c# (which you can't do).

Comment: that's perfect, thank you so much @dbc.

Comment: What is the relationship to the [tag:hidden] tag?

Comment: None at the moment @dbc. But that tag's in need of a cleanup/burnination sometime soon.

Comment: I see there's also a [tag:hide] tag: *Methods for hiding visual components, particularly with regard to HTML*  Should we be retagging posts that are really about hiding objects graphically with this tag?  Ex: [Making shapes invisible/visible in excel through VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33573566/3744182).

Comment: Given that [hide] has a burnination request of its own, I'd not use that tag. @dbc

Answer (score 60):

I agree that we should get rid of it.

Hiding can refer to:

1. members hidden using inheritance (related, but perhaps not identical, to [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overriding))
2. [encapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encapsulation)
3. hiding something ...

   > from the user

(1) and (2) seems on topic and specific and meaningful enough to justify having a tag, so we should probably just retag to more specific tags.

(3) is probably not specific enough and needs to just be removed.

---

On a related note, we should probably figure out whether we *really* need all these tags:
[name-hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/name-hiding), [method-hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-hiding), [member-hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/member-hiding), [property-hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/property-hiding), [information-hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/information-hiding), [data-hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-hiding).

The first 4 of those seem like they would relate to (1), while the last 2 would relate to (2), but I didn't really check how they're *actually* being used.

---

We should also get rid of [hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hide), and also perhaps [show-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/show-hide).
See also [​[Hide] the whole [show-hide] [show]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294340/hide-the-whole-show-hide-show?rq=1).

Comment: I'm totally going to make [raw-hide] now, just for completeness

Comment: The fact that it can refer to 3 separate things kind of implies that it's a bad tag, though - tags really should unambiguously describe the content.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I was agreeing that it should be removed - edited to clarify that.

Comment: I agree with points 1 and 2, then - it seems like those could be given more specific tags.

Comment: @Machavity Well... What about *`[cooked-hide]`* *\*I'll show myself the door now\**

Comment: @LogicalBranch You mean [prepared-hide], surely.

Comment: @MrLister I don't prepare (or wear) hide, I eat it with the meat like a man.

Comment: I think the only question is if any of the *-hiding tags should be dragged into this cleanup, or be used as retagging targets.

Comment: @MrLister I believe in the industry is called [tanned-hide]

Comment: any bama fans in here?  `[rolt-hide]`