# Synonymize [specialization] into [template-specialization]

Tags: support, synonym-request

Both tags are used to refer to the C++ concept of template specialization.

[specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specialization) has a longer wiki, but [template-specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-specialization) has more usage and a more specific name.  [template-specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-specialization) should become the master tag.

Comment: Have you verified that all 416 questions with the [[tag:specialization]] tag actually refer to template specialization? Once that's done, I see nothing blocking this.

Comment: @CodyGray Indeed, many of them don't.  Some refer to "specialization" in some vague (and not useful) sense.  Others refer to something that appears analogous to C++ template specialization but for a different language, like trait specialization in Rust.  Two are about some GHC thing.  In any case, I think one ambiguous "specialization" tag is the wrong thing to have, but I'm not sure how to untangle it.

Comment: Well, they would have to be manually disambiguated by reading and retagging them. The first step is to figure out the major ways that the tag is being used, and then how those should be retagged. [template-specialization] for C++, perhaps [trait-specialization] for Rust. What's this GHC thing? This type of disambiguation is difficult and error-prone, since none of us are experts on all languages, not to mention time-consuming and tedious.

Comment: @CodyGray We could go through and mass edit all the uses of [tag:specialization] that *are* clearly synonymous with [tag:template-specialization] - the majority - so it's easier to see what's left.

Comment: You *could*, but it would be better to just leave those questions alone and edit the incorrect ones. Then, a moderator can rename the remaining [specialization] tag to [template-specialization] with a minimal amount of fuss and disruption. In instances where the tag is a honeypot of off-topic or problematic questions, we do often have the community go through and edit all of them, but I don't think that motivation applies in this case.

Comment: Why synonymize? If you say that the [tag:specialization] is ambiguous you should propose to retag the questions, not to further enable the use of the ambiguous tag. C++ isn't the only language with a specialization feature.

Comment: A burnination is better than mass-editing if there are different use cases. But most of the [tag:specialization] questions with the [tag:templates] tag can be retagged to [tag:template-specialization].

Comment: Here are the 48 questions not related to c++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specialization%20-c%2b%2b%20-c%2b%2b11

Comment: @CodyGray [As shown below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381818/497934), I've gone through the questions tagged [tag:specialization] and found that it's used in various ways across several languages.  However, when used with [tag:c++], it's always synonymous with [tag:template-specialization].  For the C++ case, at least, can we have those questions mass-edited to use [tag:template-specialization] so that there's not an arbitrary split?

Comment: Ping @CodyGray (or anyone else with the relevant powers.)  See my comment above.

Answer (score 3):

## Useful Links

- [C++ questions with specialization but not template-specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20%5Bspecialization%5D%20-%5Btemplate-specialization%5D%20(%20%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20or%20%5Bc%2B%2B11%5D%20or%20%5Bc%2B%2B14%5D%20or%20%5Bc%2B%2B17%5D%20or%20%5Bc%2B%2B20%5D)) (to prove that the tags are synonymous in the case of C++)
- [specialization on non-C++ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20%5Bspecialization%5D%20-%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20-%5Bc%2B%2B11%5D%20-%5Bc%2B%2B14%5D%20-%5Bc%2B%2B17%5D%20-%5Bc%2B%2B20%5D) (on which the list below is based)
- [template-specialization on non-C++ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20%5Btemplate-specialization%5D%20-%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20-%5Bc%2B%2B11%5D%20-%5Bc%2B%2B14%5D%20-%5Bc%2B%2B17%5D%20-%5Bc%2B%2B20%5D) (likely its own problem, but not what I'm considering here)

## Questions by Language

If you're comfortable in any of these languages, please check the links and see if [specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specialization) is an appropriate tag for what they're talking about, or if it's avoidable by somehow making it more specific.

### C++

[specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specialization) is always synonymous with [template-specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-specialization) on C++ questions.  These can reasonably be mass-edited to use [template-specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-specialization).

### C#

- [Override And Call Base Property Set Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236874/override-and-call-base-property-set-method)
- [C#: Generics, Polymorphism And Specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486933/c-generics-polymorphism-and-specialization)
- [How can I specialize argument types for inheritors of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921460/how-can-i-specialize-argument-types-for-inheritors-of-a-class)
- [Expression trees vs IL.Emit for runtime code specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866764/expression-trees-vs-il-emit-for-runtime-code-specialization)
- [How to achieve some level of polymorphism in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160871/how-to-achieve-some-level-of-polymorphism-in-c)
- [Type specialization; how to determine and react on each specific type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519879/type-specialization-how-to-determine-and-react-on-each-specific-type)

### D

- [Multiple types in one specialized D template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878836/multiple-types-in-one-specialized-d-template)

### F

- [F# Inline Function Specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496868/f-inline-function-specialization)

### Haskell (GHC)

- [Specialization of singleton parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734362/specialization-of-singleton-parameters)
- [specialization in type classes using ghc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955711/specialization-in-type-classes-using-ghc)

### Java

- [@Specializes in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912547/specializes-in-spring)

### Julia

- [Is dispatching on value types, defined by `fieldnames` is fully determined by specialization on the type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220424/is-dispatching-on-value-types-defined-by-fieldnames-is-fully-determined-by-sp)

### PHP

- [How can I specialize a class of a namespace and use it without modifying too much code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887170/how-can-i-specialize-a-class-of-a-namespace-and-use-it-without-modifying-too-muc)

### Python:

- [How to subclass requests in python through inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327627/how-to-subclass-requests-in-python-through-inheritance)
- [When should behaviour that is to be customized in subclasses be put in seperate methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115233/when-should-behaviour-that-is-to-be-customized-in-subclasses-be-put-in-seperate)
- [Python: Explain result of the programm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438906/python-explain-result-of-the-programm)

### Rust

- [Expected output type changes when marking trait method and associated type as default for specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619059/expected-output-type-changes-when-marking-trait-method-and-associated-type-as-de)
- [How can I return specializable associated type from default method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465002/how-can-i-return-specializable-associated-type-from-default-method)
- [How does trait specialization actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600646/how-does-trait-specialization-actually-work)
- [How to implement specialized versions of a generic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471212/how-to-implement-specialized-versions-of-a-generic-function)
- [Specialize to reuse in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857673/specialize-to-reuse-in-rust)

### Scala

- [How to Run and Different Code Paths Based on Specialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794347/how-to-run-and-different-code-paths-based-on-specialisation)
- [Processing parameterized class and its sub classes in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293966/processing-parameterized-class-and-its-sub-classes-in-scala)
  *(interesting because it also tags [template-specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-specialization).)*
- [Cannot specialize a Scala method with specializable trait as return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161728/cannot-specialize-a-scala-method-with-specializable-trait-as-return-type)
- [Scala specialization for numeric operation of primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032202/scala-specialization-for-numeric-operation-of-primitive-types)
- [How can one provide manually specialized implementations with Scala specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468341/how-can-one-provide-manually-specialized-implementations-with-scala-specializati)
- [Boilerplate-free Scala ArrayBuilder specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306408/boilerplate-free-scala-arraybuilder-specialization)
- [Usage of @specialized in traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194730/usage-of-specialized-in-traits)
- [Why do these type arguments not conform to a type refinement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795623/why-do-these-type-arguments-not-conform-to-a-type-refinement)
- [How to spot boxing/unboxing in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494860/how-to-spot-boxing-unboxing-in-scala)

### Swift

- [Swift protocol specializing generic protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224234/swift-protocol-specializing-generic-protocol)
- [Wrong specialized generic function gets called in Swift 3 from an indirect call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980001/wrong-specialized-generic-function-gets-called-in-swift-3-from-an-indirect-call)

### VB.NET

- [vb.net specilized/overloaded generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023915/vb-net-specilized-overloaded-generics)
- [Specialize a generic variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328546/specialize-a-generic-variable)

### Specialization in the Modeling Sense

As opposed to generalization, as in entity-relationship models, UML, and database design.

- [How to add a foreign key constraint references to the IS-A-to-Two-Tables relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997028/how-to-add-a-foreign-key-constraint-references-to-the-is-a-to-two-tables-relatio)
- [Ensure complete disjoint specialization MySQL/JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471306/ensure-complete-disjoint-specialization-mysql-jpa)
- [EER - Restrict especializations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307976/eer-restrict-especializations)
- [MySQL Specialization/Generalization questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765966/mysql-specialization-generalization-questions)
- [Entity relationship - DB Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870542/entity-relationship-db-design)
- [About subtypes in EER Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412017/about-subtypes-in-eer-model)
- [how do I restrict multiplicity and other properties in specialized classes using UML or class definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150084/how-do-i-restrict-multiplicity-and-other-properties-in-specialized-classes-using)
- [Is there a mean to specify specialization-genralization (inheritance) of actors in UML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885410/is-there-a-mean-to-specify-specialization-genralization-inheritance-of-actors)
- [Class Table Inheritance vs. Denormalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623719/class-table-inheritance-vs-denormalization)
- [Bidirectional data population design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487740/bidirectional-data-population-design-pattern)

### Something Else / Language-Agnostic / Other / I Don't Know

- [Support for non-concrete "iN" types in LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231293/support-for-non-concrete-in-types-in-llvm)
- [Pattern where only one handler of many should act based on specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908200/pattern-where-only-one-handler-of-many-should-act-based-on-specialization)
- [Is it best for multiple specialization or single specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432107/is-it-best-for-multiple-specialization-or-single-specialization)